# Scrutor not working to automatically register the services with the ASP.NET Core DI container in case of .NET 7 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-7.0, scrutor, modular-monolith

I have created a .NET 7 Web API project using the following links :

https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/modular-architecture-in-aspnet-core/

https://medium.com/design-microservices-architecture-with-patterns/microservices-killer-modular-monolithic-architecture-ac83814f6862

In this case I am following Modular Monolithic architecture to design the solution structure.

I have a Web API project in the Host folder which references Scrutor nuget package (Version:4.2.2) to automatically register the services with the ASP.NET Core DI container (Reference : https://andrewlock.net/using-scrutor-to-automatically-register-your-services-with-the-asp-net-core-di-container/)

Here goes the code:

**AppDIExtensions.cs**

```
public static class AppDIExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddDependencies(this IServiceCollection services) =>
            services.Scan(scan => scan
                    .FromAssembliesOf(typeof(ICacheProvider))
                    .AddClasses(classes => classes.InNamespaces("Shared.Infrastructure.Services.Cloud"))
                    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                    .WithTransientLifetime()
                );
    }
```

In the above ICacheProvider is located with the Shared.Core.Abstractions.Contracts.Cloud (Part of Shared folder).

AddDependencies method is referenced from the Program.cs of API project which has reference to Module.Catalog and Shared.Infrastructure project.

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var config = builder.Configuration;

// Add AzureKeyVault
builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVaultConfiguration(config);
builder.Services.AddDependencies();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddCatalogModule(config);
builder.Services.AddSharedInfrastructure(config);
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**Solution Structure:**

[image]

Can anyone help me here with some code sample which will serve as a reference for my implementation

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue with the following code :

```
public static IServiceCollection AddDependencies(this IServiceCollection services) =>
            services.Scan(scan => scan
                    .FromApplicationDependencies()
                    .AddClasses(classes => classes.InNamespaces("Shared.Infrastructure.Services.Cloud"))
                    .UsingRegistrationStrategy(RegistrationStrategy.Skip)
                    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                    .WithTransientLifetime()
                );
```

In this case I used FromApplicationDependencies() method instead of FromAssembliesOf()